# constraint programming, repetition of number in a list, prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd, constraint-programming

How can I limit the repetition of a number in a list?

What is a suitable constraint in the following code example?

```
limit(X) :-
    length(X,10),
    domain(X,1,4),
    % WANTED CONSTRAINT: maximum repetition of each number is 5 times.
    labeling([],X).
```

Some sample queries and expected answers:

```
?- limit([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]).
false.

?- limit([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]).
true.
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a count(List, Element, Occurences) predicate?

Comment: Yes it doesnt work as it doesnt find integers to count.

Answer (score 2):

This works, L is the list of the number of repetitions of each number from 1 to 4.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

limit(X) :-
    length(L, 4),
    L ins 0..5,
    sum(L, #=, 10),
    label(L),    
    maplist(make_list, [1,2,3,4], L, LX),
    flatten([LX],X).


make_list(Val, Nb, L) :-
    length(L, Nb),
    L ins Val .. Val.
```

The problem is that the numbers are group by values.
The code may be generalized to

```
limit(X, Min, Max, Len, Rep) :-
    Nb is Max -Min + 1,
    length(L, Nb),
    L ins 0..Rep,
    sum(L, #=, Len),
    label(L),
    numlist(Min, Max, Lst),
    maplist(make_list, Lst, L, LX),
    flatten([LX],X).
```

You try :   **limit(X, 1, 4, 10, 5).**

Comment: `Ls ins Val..Val` is a neat usage of `ins/2`, very nice! As an alternative which is maybe more readable, consider: `maplist(=(Val), Ls)`.

Answer (score 2):

In this answer we use two different [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) "flavors": [sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) and [gnu-prolog](/questions/tagged/gnu-prolog).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

limited_repetitions__SICStus(Zs) :-
   length(Zs, 10),
   domain(Zs, 1, 4),
   domain([C1,C2,C3,C4], 0, 5),
   global_cardinality(Zs, [1-C1,2-C2,3-C3,4-C4]),
   labeling([], Zs).

limited_repetitions__gprolog(Zs) :-
   length(Zs, 10),
   fd_domain(Zs, 1, 4),
   maplist(fd_atmost(5,Zs), [1,2,3,4]),
   fd_labeling(Zs).
```

Simple sample query run with [SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/) version 4.3.2 and [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/) 1.4.4:

```
?- limited_repetitions__SICStus(Zs).   %  ?- limited_repetitions__gprolog(Zs).
  Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]           %    Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3]           %  ; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3]
; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4]           %  ; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4]
; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,2]           %  ; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,2]
; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]           %  ; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4]           %  ; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4]
; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,2]           %  ; Zs = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,2] 
...                                    %  ...
```

Let's measure the time required for counting the number of solutions!

```
call_succeeds_n_times(G_0, N) :-
   findall(t, call(G_0), Ts),
   length(Ts, N).

?- call_time(call_succeeds_n_times(limited_repetitions__SICStus(_), N), T_ms).
N = 965832, T_ms = 6550.               % w/SICStus Prolog 4.3.2

?- call_time(call_succeeds_n_times(limited_repetitions__gprolog(_), N), T_ms).
N = 965832, T_ms = 276.                % w/GNU Prolog 1.4.4
```

Comment: Why not define `(ins)/2` for both?

Comment: See mat's `library(clpfd)`

Comment: Great answer, `global_cardinality/2` works that way in `swi-prolog` also!

Answer (score 2):

[In this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33580288/4609915) we utilized the SICStus Prolog [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) predicate [`global_cardinality/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Arithmetic_002dLogical-Constraints.html). As an non-constraint alternative, we could also use [`selectd/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207770/4609915) like this:

```
multi_selectd_rest([],Ds,Ds).
multi_selectd_rest([Z|Zs],Ds0,Ds) :-
   selectd(Z,Ds0,Ds1),
   multi_selectd_rest(Zs,Ds1,Ds).
```

Putting it to good use in `limited_repetitions__selectd/3` we define:

```
limited_repetitions__selectd(Zs) :-
   length(Zs, 10),
   multi_selectd_rest(Zs,[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],_).
```

Again, let's measure the time required for counting the number of solutions!

```
?- call_time(call_succeeds_n_times(limited_repetitions__selectd(_),N), T_ms).
N = 965832, T_ms = 4600.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, but not for sequences:

```
:- [library(clpfd)].

limit_repetition(Xs, Max) :-
    maplist(vs_n_num(Xs, Max), Xs).

vs_n_num(Vs, Max, X) :-
    maplist(eq_b(X), Vs, Bs),
%   sum(Bs, #=, EqC),
%   EqC #=< Max.
    sum(Bs, #=<, Max).

eq_b(X, Y, B) :- X #= Y #<==> B.
```

vs_n_num/3 is an adapted version of what you can find in [docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.7%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpfd.html%27%29%29).

Here's a way to delimite sequences:

```
limit_repetition([X|Xs], Max) :-
    limit_repetition(X, 1, Xs, Max).

limit_repetition(X, C, [Y|Xs], Max) :-
    X #= Y #<==> B,
    ( B #/\ C + B #=< Max #/\ D #= C + B ) #\/ ( (#\ B) #/\ D #= 1 ),
    limit_repetition(Y, D, Xs, Max).
limit_repetition(_X, _C, [], _Max).
```

yields

```
?- length(X,4), X ins 1..4, limit_repetition(X, 1) ,label(X).
X = [1, 2, 1, 2] ;
X = [1, 2, 1, 3] ;
...
```

Seems the former version is more related to your sample.

Comment: You can use `sum(Bs, #=<, Max)`.